# Как делаются такие шары?

Tags: css, scss

Какие свойства нужны чтобы получить такой шар?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думал что нужен **background: linear-gradient** и  **filter: blur**.
Но я уже вижу что результат будет другой, не как на первом изображении.

```css
div {
position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #d5d5d5, #831F10);
    border-radius: 100%;
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: https://webref.ru/css/value/radial-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все градиенты могут иметь больше, чем два цвета. В представленном исходном изображении именно такая ситуация - используется три цвета.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--size);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  height: 66%;
  width: 66%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #951c04 10%, #f97f06, #e6e6e6 80%);
  filter: blur(calc(var(--size) / 10));
}
```

```html
<div style="--size: 300px"></div>
<div style="--size: 200px"></div>
<div style="--size: 100px"></div>
```

Comment: нужно резкость навести или экран протереть, слишком размыто все :-D

Comment: @Grundy, вот же, млин!.. А я думал, что это мне спросонья так кажется :-D